# Search Bar in Django

Tags: django

**EDIT: I managed to include a Search bar using 'DjangoFilter'**

I would like to add a search bar to my template in Django

I would like to include a search box in above a list of articles so users can search through the data.

When I enter something in the bar nothing happens though...
here below my code

Thanks for the help in advance
In HTML page

```
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" >
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

In views.py

```
def article_overview(request):
    search_term = ''

    if 'search' in request.GET:
        search_term = request.GET['search']
        articles = Article.objects.all().filter(feeder__icontains=search_term) 

    articles = Article.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'overviews/overview.html', {'articles' : articles, 'search_term': search_term })
```

in overview.html(simplified):

```
{% for article in articles %}
<a> {{article.feeder}} </a> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: your `if` clause doesn't do anything because you always override `articles` with `Article.objects.all()`. Check the flow of your code...

Comment: Thanks. Though, still doesn't work. should I include the search_term in my template tags as well?

Comment: So what have you changed? You’ve added `else`? And when you say “nothing happens” what do you mean exactly? Really nothing happens?

Comment: the search is not "executed". nothing happens in the web browser. I have corrected the name of the variable as you suggested

Comment: I didn’t suggest to change a name. I just said that your line `articles = Article.objects.all()` always gets executed so your view always shows all articles regardless of the search. You can remove the `if` clause entirely, that’s what your code does.

Comment: Nothing happens in the browser? So the page isn’t refreshed and the search input field not emptied?

Comment: Hi dirkgroten. the search input field in the url bar is not emptied no. It stays like this (example: ?search=abc)

Comment: First move `articles = Article.objects.all()` above the `if` clause. Then check in your browser developer tools if the form is submitted when clicking the search button. Or set a breakpoint in you python `get` method and check what’s submitted.

Comment: " EDIT: I managed to include a Search bar using 'DjangoFilter' "
Can you better explain please? You can answer your own question and show the community how you succeed. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In views.py,

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'search.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
       result = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
       query = self.request.GET.get('search')
       if query:
          postresult = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=query)
          result = postresult
       else:
           result = None
       return result
```

In your template to search query,

```
<form class="add_your_class" method="GET" action="" >
    <input class="add_your_class" type="search" name="search"> 
    <button class="add_your_class" type="submit"> Search </button>
</form>
```

In templates you can add it as to show results

```
{% for result in all_search_results %}
   {{ .....add according to your model }}
{% empty %}
   add something to show no results
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Anything to add in the url view?

Comment: url view? If you are asking about url path, then you don't need as you are searching for the query. As you have many answers on this post, mark as correct to whichever answer working for you. That will help someone else who is searching for same.

Comment: Hi Bidhan. none worked. But I've put an edit at the top explaining I managed to clear the point using django-filter. Best,

Answer (score 2):

My example worked in my case:
base template:

```
form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action="{% url 'ecomm:search' %}" >
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="search">
            <button class="btn btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"> Search </button>
        </form>
```

search template:

```
{% extends "ecomm/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for product in all_search_results %}
        <h3>{{product.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        <img src="{{ product.picture.url }}">
    {% empty %}
        <h2>No results found</h2>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

the view:

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    model = Products
    template_name = 'ecomm/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_search_results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(SearchView, self).get_queryset()
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        if query:
            postresult = Products.objects.filter(title__contains=query)
            result = postresult
        else:
            result = None
        return result
```

the url:

```
    path('results/', ecomm_views.SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is to use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) which inlcude a search bar by default. Put your fields in each row and search it out that way.

```
<table id="articles" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Feeder</th>
     </tr> 
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {% for article in articles %}
      <tr>
          <td>{{article.feeder}</td> 
      </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#articles').DataTable();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your articles saved in your database, what you can do is have a datalist for your input, use AJAX to prepopulate the datalist with the articles from your database so that you have some sort of an autocomplete dropdown/search box.

There's an excellent tutorial from Teamtreehouse.com for this implementation. Here's the [link](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element).

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning article variable in two places, therefore you're overwriting the first one. Rename article variable inside if statement and pass that to template

```
if 'search' in request.GET:
    search_term = request.GET['search']
    search_result = Article.objects.all().filter(feeder__icontains=search_term) 

articles = Article.objects.all()

return render(request, 'overviews/overview.html', {'articles' : articles, 'search_result': search_result })
```

Comment: still doesn't work.. should i make a change to my template tags ?

Comment: Of course, you need to render results queryset. It's as simple as:
{% for result in search_result %}
{{ result.fieldname }}
{% endfor }}
P.S. notice that 'fieldname' should be name of your model field.

Comment: hi Renato. ok but I already had template tags to display the entire list? cf via articles.. how to combine?

Comment: These are two separate querysets. Merging them together wouldn't make sense because in articles you allready retrieve all objects and by merging them you would get duplicates in your list.

Comment: in html change {{articles.feeder}} to {{item.feeder}}

Comment: oops. was only error on my side when writing my question here. doesn't resolve the issue in my actual code.